# Android: Save image to gallery from web screen

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have a simple Android app which is just a collection of webviews. Normally in the default Android browser or Chrome, the user can long press on an image and save it to their phone.

In the webview, the user doesnt have an option for long-pressing, but I'd like to be able to offer the same functionality for saving images to their phone.

Is this possible through javascript or jquery, or any other method?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appears you have at least two (non-deprecated) options:

- getHitTestResult() Ref: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult%28%29)
- requestImageRef(Message msg) Ref: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#requestImageRef%28android.os.Message%29)

For first option, Gets a HitTestResult based on the current cursor node. If a HTML::a tag is found and the anchor has a non-JavaScript URL, the HitTestResult type is set to SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE and the URL is set in the "extra" field. If the anchor does not have a URL or if it is a JavaScript URL, the type will be UNKNOWN_TYPE and the URL has to be retrieved through requestFocusNodeHref(Message) asynchronously. If a HTML::img tag is found, the HitTestResult type is set to IMAGE_TYPE and the URL is set in the "extra" field. A type of SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE indicates an anchor with a URL that has an image as a child node. If a phone number is found, the HitTestResult type is set to PHONE_TYPE and the phone number is set in the "extra" field of HitTestResult. If a map address is found, the HitTestResult type is set to GEO_TYPE and the address is set in the "extra" field of HitTestResult. If an email address is found, the HitTestResult type is set to EMAIL_TYPE and the email is set in the "extra" field of HitTestResult. Otherwise, HitTestResult type is set to UNKNOWN_TYPE.

**For Second Option:**

```
public void requestImageRef (Message msg)
```

It Requests the URL of the image last touched by the user. msg will be sent to its target with a String representing the URL as its object

Not sure if these options are compatible with a 'long click' too though.

you may also be able to simply capture all loaded image resources using onLoadResource(WebView view, String url), build a list of image references and download the one that button click refers too.